# JavaScript: Date object convert to string when sent to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

**Summary of Problem**

I have a React Native application where I create a date object, assign it to **startTime** and send it via Axios to my backend end node.js server.  When I typeof console.log the variable immediately after receiving it in the backend, the type is a string.  I have done typeof console.logs in the front end to make sure it is a date object all the way up until it is sent via Axios to the backend.

This may be a axios or HTTPS thing I'm not familiar with as I'm a new developer.  Any help would be greatly appreciate it.  I've included all relevant code below but let me know if you think I should include more.

***Code***

***React Native API Call***
startTime console logs as an object

```
export const confirmDailyComp = async data =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const { userId, compName, startTime, competitors, lengthType, privacyType  } = data; //FIXME: add competition back here, took it out to throw error on purpose
    console.log('confirmDailyComp typeof startTime', typeof startTime) //this console logs as an object
    try {
      const response = await http.post("/v1/route", {
        userId,
        compName,
        startTime,
        competitors,
        lengthType, 
        privacyType
      });
      const competition = response.data.newComp;
      resolve(competition);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error fetching friends", err);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
```

**Node.js Controller**

startTime console logs as a string

There is of course more code in the rest of the route but I didn't include it to be concise.  I'm happy to include it if you think its necessary.

```
start: async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const {
        competitors,
        startTime,
        userId,
        compName,
        privacyType,
        lengthType,
        seasonNum
      } = req.body;
      console.log("typeof startDate", typeof startTime); // console logs as a string
} catch(err) {
}
```

Comment: HTTP is a text transfer protocol. Client-side data types are not persisted as those types on the server. You will need to do a server-side conversion. You might consider sending the data in JSON format to more easily get it back to a Date on the server.

Comment: ok great, thanks Scott!  Good suggestion on the JSON because JSON.parse would solve my problem right?  For now since it's not JSON I just did startTime = new Date(startTime); to get it back to being a date object.  Do you think that's a good bandaid solution for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript Date is an object, and JSON specification doesn't have date.
This is why when you send it through JSON it will be serialized as string, because Axios by default will serialize it as UTC format string.

You have three options:

1. understand they are UTC string and you create a date object which can parse them correctly.
2. convert the date yourself to its numeric format.
3. The third option is the JSON.parse method has an optional parameter to pass your custom parser, which you can use it to build a custom date parser.
   You can get an idea from this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try considering sending `startTime` as a timestamp(something like `1567114948292`).

Now you can take this value in the server and get the time.